# Where's a good location for crafting?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I like to craft new items, since they tend to be more powerful than what I can find or buy.  However, I've yet to find a good location to do my crafting.  Ideally this place would have:

- A fast travel waypoint (so I can get in and out quickly)
- A stash (so I can dump unique or set items I've found)
- A blacksmith forge (so I can craft armor and weapons)
- An altar for sagecrafting (so I can craft gems to become part of my items)

I'd also like to have close by:

- A shop (to sell unwanted items)
- An alchemy workbench (for restocking my potions)

At the moment, I'm using the Canneroc area, which has the stash, alchemy bench, and sagecrafting altar in Gossamer End, and the nearby blacksmith forge location has a shopkeeper wandering around nearby.  However, it's a bit inconvenient to zone two or three times to swap between the areas, and the sagecrafting altar is way down in the basement of the house.

Are there any areas that meet these qualifications?  If I need to run a quest line to unlock/upgrade a house, that's fine, but please make note of it.

Comment: I was going to suggest Gossamer's End... :/ You people on the xbox and your load times. Pfah.

Comment: This is a useful question. If 5 people found @RavenDreamer's answer to be useful, 5 people should upvote the question that prompted the answer. /petpeeve

Comment: @Gumbz I think you mean Sterno. I haven't posted an answer.

Comment: Yes. That guy! He rocks. Carry on.

Comment: @Gumbz It's entirely possible for an answer to be better than the question that prompted it. I often upvote answers without upvoting the question. This particular question has nothing wrong with it, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To meet all of the criteria you listed, sadly, Canneroc was the best I found (once you get and upgrade your house). Most of the other stashes require too much running from the fast travel point to make them useful.

However, what I found while playing is that there were some locations that were good to go to if you wanted a smaller subset of actions (i.e., if you didn't need to hit your stash).

Of the maps I'm showing, the fast-travel spawn point is circled in green. Stashes (if any) are in red and the crafting stations and shopkeepers are in orange. The "load screen" count includes warping in to the town in the first place.

---

### Canneroc (best for stash + all crafting)

> ## Load Screens To Hit Everything: 5
>
> In my opinion, Canneroc is the best place to go if you need to hit
> your stash. The spawn point is right in front of your house, which
> also contains sagecrafting + alchemy. Unfortunately you have to run
> across the street to do blacksmithing and selling. You end up up
> seeing 5 loading screens by the time you warp there and run in and out
> of everything. Still the winner if you need your stash, though. Not
> only does it take longer to get to your house in Adessa and Rathir
> (waaaaay longer in Rathir), but once you get inside your house, you've
> got quite a run to get to the stash in either case, versus it being
> right inside the front door in Canneroc.

[image: canneroc]

---

### Didenhil (best for all crafting + sales, but no stash)

> ## Load Screens To Hit Everything: 3
>
> Didenhil is a pretty solid choice if you don't need to hit your stash
> but you want all the crafting types. You've got Alchemy,
> Blacksmithing, Sagecrafting, and shopkeepers all inside the same room
> not far from the warp-in point. You'll only have to see 3 loading
> screens by the time you warp there, run in, and run out.

[image: Didenhil]

---

### Mel Senshir (best load time if you don't need stash or Alchemy)

> ## Load Screens To Hit Everything: 1
>
> Once I got to Mel Senshir, this is what I ended up using most of the
> time, with an occasional trip to Canneroc just to drop items in my
> stash. The main thing this one has going for it is that the warp-in
> point is right next to two shopkeepers, and while the crafting
> stations are a short run away, they are in the same zone as the
> warp-in point, meaning you don't have to see any loading screens to
> get to them. If load times are a pain for you, this will probably be
> the one to go to. Since I found Alchemy to be a waste of time in the
> game, this was my preferred salvaging/selling/crafting point.

[image: MelSenshir]

---

I can't say that there's absolutely nothing better out there, but through the 40+ hours I played, these were the ones that seemed the least painful to me. Basically, I ignored Alchemy as a waste of time, used Canneroc to hit my stash, and use Mel Senshir for everything else. Before I had access to Mel Senshir I used Didenhil instead.

Comment: +1 I have over 100 hours in this game, and also find alchemy to be nearly useless. I also rarely need to access my stash, so Didenhill and Mel Senshir are the best spots. Canneroc is too much of a hassle.